# Definition of a bilinear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $E^2$ a vector space and $\big\{e_1,e_2\big\}$ its basis, then $f$ is bilinear map, and two vectors $x,y\in E^2$ s.t. $x=ae_1+be_2$ and $y=ce_1+de_2$
>
> I don't understand why
>
> $f(x,y)=f(ae_1+be_2,ce_1+de_2) =acf(e_1,e_1)+adf(e_1,e_2)+bcf(e_2,e_1)+bdf(e_2,e_2)$

According to what I understood, I would write it like that :

I fix the second argument in red
$f(x,y)=f(ae_1+be_2,\color {red}{ce_1+de_2}) =\underbrace{f(ae_1,\color {red}{ce_1+de_2})}_{1}+\underbrace{f(be_2,\color {red}{ce_1+de_2})}_{2}$

I fix the first argument

$(1)\quad f(\color {red}{ae_1},ce_1+de_2)=f(\color {red}{ae_1},ce_1)+f(\color {red}{ae_1},de_2)$

$(2)\quad f(\color {red}{be_2},ce_1+de_2)=f(\color {red}{be_2},ce_1)+f(\color {red}{be_2},de_2)$

$f(x,y)=(1)+(2)= f(ae_1,ce_1)+f(ae_1,de_2)+f(be_2,ce_1)+f(be_2,de_2)$

And the step I don't understand is why $f(ae_1,ce_1)=acf(e_1,e_1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(ae_1,ce_1)=acf(e_1,e_1)$ because $f$ is bilinear (meaning linear in both arguments).

Since $f$ is linear in the first argument, $f(ae_1,ce_1)=af(e_1,ce_1)$.

Since $f$ is linear in the second argument, $af(e_1,ce_1)=acf(e_1,e_1)$.

Comment: If $f(ae_1,ce_1)=acf(e_1,e_1)$ Does it mean $acf(e_1,e_1)=f(ace_1,ace_1)$?

Comment: No: $f(ace_1,ace_1)=a^2c^2f(e_1,e_1)$

Comment: So $af(e_1,e_2)=f(ae_1,e_2)=f(e_1,ae_2)$, is it right, and if it is not how do I know how to dispatch the coefficient $a$

Comment: Yes, that's right. Whenever you have a scalar inside either argument, it can be taken outside.